# How to write a NWProtocolFramer for Network.framework that splits streams into frames using a delimiter?

Tags: swift, tcp, network.framework

I tried the following code to create a framer that splits a stream of ASCII bytes into frames separated by the pipe ascii character: `"|"`.

```
import Network

fileprivate let pipe = Character("|").asciiValue!

class PipeFramer: NWProtocolFramerImplementation {
    static let label = "Pipe framer"
    static let definition = NWProtocolFramer.Definition(implementation: PipeFramer.self)

    var minLengthUntilNextMessage = 1 {
        didSet { print("client: minLength set to", minLengthUntilNextMessage) }
    }

    required init(framer: NWProtocolFramer.Instance) {}

    func start(framer: NWProtocolFramer.Instance) -> NWProtocolFramer.StartResult { .ready }

    func handleInput(framer: NWProtocolFramer.Instance) -> Int {
        while true {
            var delimiterPosition: Int?
            _ = framer.parseInput(minimumIncompleteLength: minLengthUntilNextMessage, maximumLength: 65535) { buffer, endOfMessage in
                if let buffer = buffer {
                    print("client: parsing buffer: \"\(String(bytes: buffer, encoding: .utf8) ?? buffer.debugDescription)\"")
                    if let indexOfDelimiter = buffer.firstIndex(of: pipe) {
                        minLengthUntilNextMessage = 1
                        delimiterPosition = indexOfDelimiter
                    } else {
                        minLengthUntilNextMessage = buffer.count + 1
                    }
                } else {
                    print("client: no buffer")
                }
                return 0
            }

            if let length = delimiterPosition {
                guard framer.deliverInputNoCopy(length: length, message: .init(instance: framer), isComplete: true) else {
                    return 0
                }
                _ = framer.parseInput(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: 65535) { _,_ in 1 }
            } else {
                return minLengthUntilNextMessage
            }
        }
    }

    func handleOutput(framer: NWProtocolFramer.Instance, message: NWProtocolFramer.Message, messageLength: Int, isComplete: Bool) {
        try! framer.writeOutputNoCopy(length: messageLength)
        framer.writeOutput(data: [pipe])
    }

    func wakeup(framer: NWProtocolFramer.Instance) {}

    func stop(framer: NWProtocolFramer.Instance) -> Bool { return true }

    func cleanup(framer: NWProtocolFramer.Instance) { }
}
```

The problem is that from the moment I get a chunk that does not end with `"|"`, the framer gets stuck on that chunk. So the other chunks that come after this incomplete chunk never fully arrive in the `framer.parseInput(...)` call. Because it always parses chunks of `minimumIncompleteLength` and hence never arrives to the point where the next `"|"` is.

Here is a simple reproduction of this problem:

1. Create a TCP server
2. Setup the server so that it sends chunks of messages when a client connects.
3. Connect to the server (created in 1.) using the framer from above.
4. Start receiving messages.

Swift Code:

```
import Network

let client = DispatchQueue(label: "Server")
let server = DispatchQueue(label: "Client")
let networkParameters = NWParameters.tcp
networkParameters.defaultProtocolStack.applicationProtocols.insert(NWProtocolFramer.Options(definition: PipeFramer.definition), at: 0)
let server = try! NWListener(using: .tcp)

server.newConnectionHandler = { connection in
    print("server: new connection from", connection.endpoint)

    print("server (client \(connection.endpoint)): state", connection.state)

    connection.viabilityUpdateHandler = { viable in
        print("server (client \(connection.endpoint)): state", connection.state)
        if viable {
            print("server: sending")
            connection.send(content: "A|Be||Sea".data(using: .utf8)!, isComplete: false, completion: .idempotent)

            serverQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
                print("server: sending second part")
                connection.send(content: " is longer than expected|0|".data(using: .utf8)!, isComplete: true, completion: .idempotent)
            }
            serverQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 8) {
                print("server: sending last part")
                connection.send(content: "Done|".data(using: .utf8)!, isComplete: true, completion: .idempotent)
            }
        }
    }

    connection.start(queue: serverQueue)
}

server.stateUpdateHandler = { state in
    print("server:", state)
    if state == .ready, let port = server.port {
        print("server: listening on", port)
    }
}

server.start(queue: serverQueue)

let client = NWConnection(to: .hostPort(host: "localhost", port: server.port!), using: networkParameters)

func receiveNext() {
    client.receiveMessage { (data, context, complete, error) in
        let content: String
        if let data = data {
            content = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? data.description
        } else {
            content = data?.debugDescription ?? "<no data>"
        }
        print("client: received \"\(content)\"", context.debugDescription, complete, error?.localizedDescription ?? "No error")

        receiveNext()
    }
}

client.stateUpdateHandler = { state in
    print("client:", state)

    if state == .ready {
        print("client: receiving")
        receiveNext()
    }
}

client.start(queue: clientQueue)
```

Results in:

```
server: waiting(POSIXErrorCode: Network is down)
server: ready
server: listening on 54894
client: preparing
client: ready
client: receiving
server: new connection from ::1.53179
server (client ::1.53179): state setup
server (client ::1.53179): state ready
server: sending
client: parsing buffer: "A|Be||Sea"
client: minLength set to 1
client: parsing buffer: "Be||Sea"
client: minLength set to 1
client: parsing buffer: "|Sea"
client: minLength set to 1
client: parsing buffer: "Sea"
client: minLength set to 4
client: parsing buffer: ""
client: minLength set to 1
client: received "A" Optional(Network.NWConnection.ContentContext) true No error
client: received "Be" Optional(Network.NWConnection.ContentContext) true No error
client: received "<no data>" Optional(Network.NWConnection.ContentContext) true No error
client: parsing buffer: "Sea"
client: minLength set to 4
server: sending second part
client: parsing buffer: "Sea "
client: minLength set to 5
client: parsing buffer: "Sea i"
client: minLength set to 6
server: sending last part
client: parsing buffer: "Sea is"
client: minLength set to 7
client: parsing buffer: "Sea is "
client: minLength set to 8
```

Notice that the fourth and fifth message are never received by the client. How should I write the Framer so that it receives messages after an incoming incomplete chunk?

---

### References

- [A swift package containing the above code](https://github.com/Dev1an/Simple-Framer)
- [Corresponding discussion on  Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663281)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem... The network protocol that I was working with also had a simple delimiter that separated each 'message' and the protocol had no header that told me what to expect. Often at the end of the buffer, there was only a partial message with no delimiter and needed to read more bytes to get the remainder of the message. Something like this:

```
|              PACKET A              |              PACKET B             |
|<message>|<message>|<message><mess...age>|<message><message><message><m...essage>
     1         2         4      5a    5b      6        7        8      9a    9b

Note:
delimiter = | - single character
lhsMessage = message 5a 
rhsMessage = message 5b
```

Even after watching WWDC and looking at the other examples from Apple, I still do not completely understand how **handleInput** and **parseInput** are supposed to function.

I assumed I could simply return from **handleInput** with the (`lhsMessage.count + 1`) and it would keep the partial message in the current **buffer** AND add additional bytes into the buffer (ie from PACKET B) that parseInput could inspect.

However, it does appear to work that way. Instead I ended up storing the value of **lhsMessage** in a class var and then returned `lhsMessage.count` from **parseInput**, which I believe moves the ‘cursor’ in the buffer to end and forces handleInput to get the new packet (ie packet B).

As part of **parseInput**, I then check if I have a `lhsMessage` and then assume if I find a delimiter that it is in fact `rhsMessage`. I then join LHS and RHS to create a `completeMessage`. At this point, I also return from **parseInput** the value of (`rhsMessage.count + 1`) to move the cursor along again.

Now to send this `completeMessage` I could not use **deliverInputNoCopy** as the bytes that make up completeMessage were no longer in the buffer :-)

Instead handleInput sent the message back using **deliverInput**.